# if-else statement print does not match after checking through statement

Tags: python

I'm working on a simple if-else statement, however after running through the if-else check, it returns only the else value, despite inputs that matches the if and elif statement:

```
testing = input("Input: ")

a = ""
b = ""

if testing == a:
    print_value = "a"

elif testing == b:
    print_value = "b"

else:
    print_value = "N/A"

print(print_value)
```

Example Result after inputting "a":

```
Expected Result: a
Final Result: N/A
```

How may I resolve this to ensure it matches the if-elif statement above?

Comment: `a` and `b`are both the empty string. Your input is `"a"`. `"a"` does not equal `""` so none of your conditions will match (except `else`) The same would be true for `b`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant something like `a = "a"` and `b = "b"` in your initialisations?

Comment: In short, try something like `testing == "a"` instead. The `a` and `b` variables aren't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the `a` and `b` an empty string and then checking if `''` is equal to `'a'`, which you can see are not equal.

Try assigning alphabets to the variables and then perform equality check.

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
```